# How can I select series in a pandas dataframe where every element in the series meets a criterion?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to get all the series in my dataframe where every element in the series passes a check (for example, every value is less than 0).

I tried:

```
dataframe[dataframe<=0]
```

and that seems to give me all the elements of each series that are less than zero.

Then I tried

```
dataframe[dataframe<=0].dropna()
```

to try to get rid of the series that have invalid values, but that gives me...something that I don't really understand.

How can I get all the elements in a dataframe that are less than zero (or more generally, all elements that meet a condition)?

Comment: Have you looked at the online docs for [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and also [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html)? `dropna` by default will drop rows where any values are `NaN`, what do you want to achieve? dropping entire series (columns) that have any `NaN`? If so do `dataframe[dataframe<=0].dropna(axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks, the axis=1 solved it! If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `axis=1` as a param to `dropna` in order for it to consider whether it is dealing row-wise or column-wise as the criteria for dropping values. By default it is row-wise.

```
dataframe[dataframe<=0].dropna(axis=1)
```

Check the online docs for [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and the overall section on [working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) to see other ways of dealing with `NaN` values.